# Warning: Unfamiliar unsecured document opened

Tags: ms-word, genero, libdl

I am editing a Word document in Genero Enterprise. Before opening the document I receive the following warning:

[image: Microsoft Word warning]

This translates to:

> Unfamiliar unsecured document opened.

This suggests that the user who created the document is not the same as the one trying to edit it, but that's not true.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "editing a Word document in Genero Enterprise" as you would not open it in Genero Studio.  You might mean that you are opening it from a Genero application using launchURL or shellexec front-call.  Also please clarify what front-end you are using GDC-Direct, GDC via HTTP, GBC, that may provide a clue as to the issue I suspect you are encountering

Comment: It is an application written with Genero Studio. The code invokes a VBA script that spits out the error. I mark this issue as resolved, since this warning was contained in the VBA script and I have commented that code for now.

Comment: In that case you are likely using an execute (or shellexec) front-call via GDC.  The process owner is the owner of the GDC process, which is not necessarily the same as the person running the fglrun process and/or who created the Word document

Comment: I see. So the error is popping up because the original author of the code doesn't correspond to the one running it. Am I right? This code snippet must be removed then. It doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: It is hard to confirm anything without knowing the code, versions, products in use.  I covered the potential scenario of what I think maybe happening in this article https://4js.com/ask-reuben/ig-44/ , look for paragraph beginning "Who is the process owner"  .  What I think in your scenario is "Ajita" wrote the Word Document and has set permissions so that only they can edit it.  Your Genero application is trying to open this document, only the name of the process owner is not "Ajita" and so you get that error.